# Shopify: accessing subscription segments

Tags: shopify, subscription

I’ve created a custom Admin API connection for shopify.

I’m able to pull down orders, customers, and products.

I can’t seem to access the subscription contract information. When I try it says I don’t have access, but don’t see this as a scope in the API scopes on Shopify.

Any ideas on how I can access this? I’d like to break down customer orders between subscription orders and manual orders

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: what are the current scopes, you are added to the app and which API method is used for develop APP. Graphql or REST admin api?

Comment: Thanks, Onkar. I’ve enabled all write-only scopes, and I’m using REST through Python, but have also tried using GraphQL. With the REST API, I can’t access subscription contracts at all. With GraphQL it at least returns a “not permissioned” response

Comment: Probably you are missing **Read all orders scope** if you are trying to read orders older than 60 days ?

Comment: Try `read_payment_terms` and `write_payment_terms` with GraphQL, I think this adds to the GraphQL version only.

Comment: I’ve found this which seems to state that custom apps can’t access subscription contracts: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/selling-strategies/subscriptions/contracts/update